# Does Windows CE support hash tables?

Tags: windows-ce, hashtable

Quick question of does Windows CE support hash tables? I have a program that I'm modifying and adding to a device that uses Windows CE and I was wondering if CE supported hash tables since it is used in the original software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[link text](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~cwc22/hashtable/)I've been waiting to see if someone smarter than I had a different take on this question.  No one seems to, so I'm going to assume everyone is confused like me.  What exactly do you mean here?

According to Wikipedia:

> A hash table or hash map is a data
>   structure that uses a hash function to
>   efficiently map certain identifiers or
>   keys (e.g., person names) to
>   associated values (e.g., their
>   telephone numbers).

Which pretty much aligns with my understanding of them.  So it's a data structure.  An OS itself doesn't really have any concept of a hash table - the language you're writing in does.  Every language that I'm aware of that supports building for Windows CE supports data structures (what kind of language wouldn't?).

- If you're writing in C# or VB.NET, you have the [Hashtable class](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~cwc22/hashtable/).
- STL has [the hash_map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d462wfh(v=VS.80).aspx)
- ATL has the [CAtlMap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6fwh89e(v=VS.80).aspx)
- MFC has the [CMap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z(v=VS.71).aspx)
- If you don't like any of those, you can always write your own or use [someone elses](http://www.cpp4u.com/c++/hash_table.html).
- For straight C it's pretty easy to find [an implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx).
- I don't do much Java work, but I'm certain there's a Hashtable class there too

So, I guess it comes back to you.  What exactly do you mean by "if CE supported hash tables"?

Comment: You basically answered the question. I've seen before code for software to go on a normal PC that did not work using Windows CE. I can't think of any of the examples right now but I was trying to find out if that would be a problem here. And from reading what you have typed, it won't. So thanks.